# save data to file or db and retrieve to the same page while loading it in iframe

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, excel, iframe

I have got this project that uses excel for some calculation.

This excel is converted to HTML using 3rd party tool. and the uploaded to server.
when a person views this HTML (i.e. in IFrame), the user can enter some data modify some data and then can save it in database or XML.

after words when later the same user wants to come and review his changes, the data must be taken from database and then must be able to view that data in HTML page which is in iframe.

But the problem here is that the user will not be able to write the code for data retrieval when retrieving data from database.

Is there any solution for that in any language or any other way of doing the same functionality??

**EDIT : Explanation**

Let me write this in steps:

1.admin uploads HTML file to web app, converted from excel using Spreadsheet converter (Third party tool).

2.user views the file, but HTML file is displayed inside iframe so not much interaction possible between parent and iframe window.

3.the HTML Page has submit button, which when clicked submits to `submit.aspx` and saves data to XML file for that user's id (with some editted values.).

4.later when same user tries to access that file,obviously it will show the file from the mentioned `src` so user stored value will not be displayed.

5.So now what i need is when user accesses the same file again the file should display the data with the values stored for that user that too without requiring any coding on that HTML page which will be viewed on that Iframe.

I want to get the interaction between top window and iframe window .i tried to achieve this using `jquery` but it is not working. Here is the code that i have tried.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var $currIFrame = $('#htmlPageFrame');
$('#htmlPageFrame').load(function() {
$currIFrame.contents().find('#userID').val('1');
$currIFrame.contents().find('#DataMode').val('save');
});
</script>
```

where `userID` and `DataMode` are to hidden fields in the HTML pge which load in iframe. Hope this makes things preety clear.

Comment: the above jquery is not working have used proper jquery plugin but still not working

Comment: @RohitWagh I have lost you, I do not understand what is the problem, where the user can not write later ?

Comment: @Aristos I have edited the question with some step-by-step explanation. hope it helps to understand my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason for problem.
As i was using master page and was making iframe `runat=server`, page was looking for `htmlPageFrame` while what i should have provided was `htmlPageFrame.ClientID`.

Silly mistake...

And Thanks @Aristos Even your solution was helpful to me.

Now code goes like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var $currIFrame = $('#<%= htmlPageFrame.ClientID %>');
$('#<%= htmlPageFrame.ClientID %>').load(function() {
$currIFrame.contents().find('#userID').val('1');
$currIFrame.contents().find('#DataMode').val('save');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 between top window and iframe window
```

### From iframe

From iframe you make calls to top window using the `window.top.document` Make your calls like

```
$('#IdOnTopWindow', window.top.document)
```

From top frame you get the iframe values by using the id of it.

### From top page

you can get  the values from the iframe, using this decleration

```
$("#userID", window.htmlPageFrame.document)
```

where htmlPageFrame is the ID of your iframe

Hope this help you to move on.

Comment: this is a good example but,i want to make calls from top window to iframe window and NOT vice versa

Comment: @RohitWagh change the window.top.document with the id of your iframe. I make some test and come back

Comment: @RohitWagh I make some test and found it, and update the answer. This way at least to me is work, test it out.

Comment: Thanks @Aritos this one helped me but found the solution for my problem. have posted it as answer.